# Simular um "ok" via linha de comando

Tags: windows, batch, cmd, proxy

Eu tenho um comando do prompt do Windows que desabilita as configurações de proxy:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Os browsers do meu sistema estão configurados pra usar as configurações do meu sistema. O comando funciona, mas não em tempo real - os efeitos só acontecem quando eu vou no menu do Windows do configuração de proxy e clico no "ok" ali.

[image: Ok?]

Como eu faço pra simular esse "ok" via prompt?

Comment: Você tem como usar de várias formas, só precisa antes testar as teclas, ver como ela interagem c a “interface”, dai usa-las no código para configurar o que for necessário..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>**`• Testado nas seguintes versões do Windows® •:`**</kbd>
 <kbd>**`XP Pro 32 bits, 7 Pro 64 bits, 8.0 Pro 64 bits & 10 Pro 64 bits`**</kbd>

---

**::** Acredito que você possa fazer uso do **sendKey** (*em **VBS***), pra fazer uns **envios de teclas** de atalho, como **TABs**,  **Setas**, **Etc..** necessárias para **chegar** ao **botão** <kbd>**`OK`**</kbd> e em seguida enviar o <kbd>**[`ENTER`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243689/simular-um-ok-via-linha-de-comando)**</kbd>, que vai funcionar como um <kbd>**[`Click!!`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243689/simular-um-ok-via-linha-de-comando)**</kbd>

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>"%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1500
     echo/ objShell.AppActivate "inetcpl.cpl"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 100
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({UP})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "(+{TAB})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "(+{UP})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 2000
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
    ) & set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs" 

start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\inetcpl.cpl" 
start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\wScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!"
del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & goto :eof
```

> **Obs.:** Para abrir direto a aba **"conexões"** via **cmd/bat**, use o **comando abaixo**:
>
> <kbd>**`start "" /w rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL Inetcpl.cpl,,4`**</kbd>
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> <kbd>**`Update: Setando home page e VPN`**</kbd>

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>"%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrHomePage  = "http://www.google.com/ncr"
     echo/ StringProxy  = "http://proxy.stackoverflow.com.br:3128"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 100
     echo/ objShell.AppActivate "inetcpl.cpl"
     echo/ for h=1 To Len^(StrHomePage^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrHomePage,h,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 150
     echo/ Next
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({UP})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 100
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "(+{TAB})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 100
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "(+{UP})"
     echo/ for i=1 to 3
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/    Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ Next
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({BACKSPACE})"
     echo/ for j=1 To Len^(StringProxy^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StringProxy,j,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 150
     echo/ Next 
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys "({END})"
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys " "
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys "2"
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/    Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ for k=1 to 3
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/    Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ Next
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ for l=1 to 5
     echo/    WshShell.SendKeys "({TAB})"
     echo/    Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ Next
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/
    ) & set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"

start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\inetcpl.cpl"
start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\wScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!"  
del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" && goto :eof
```

---

Answer (score 4):

Isso não é possível, e por um bom motivo.

Imagine se fosse possível simular cliques de mouse pelo usuário. Apenas imagine, por um instante.

Agora imagine um malware que faz isso.

Agora imagine que assim você poderia:

- Desabilitar Firewall e Windows Defender;
- Desabilitar anti-vírus;
- Mandar itens para a lixeira;
- Esvaziar a lixeira;
- Deslogar o usuário;
- Desligar a máquina;
- Com um pouco de imaginação, você poderia ter um serviço que observa que processos o usuário abre. Espere ele abrir um navegador, entrar em um site de internet banking com layout conhecido... Simule uma tela falsa, mande a janela do navegador para lá, e transfira o dinheiro do usuário para uma conta temporária sua.

Por essas razões, muita coisa que lida com segurança da máquina requer no mínimo uma confirmação do usuário. As vezes pedem um envolvimento que vai além disso.

Em tempo: você está uns dezenove anos atrasado no conceito desse seu vírus. O [Culto da Vaca Morta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_the_Dead_Cow) inventou o [Back Orifice](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_Orifice) para fazer coisas como o que você quer. Felizmente e para o bem da humanidade, isso já não é mais tão fácil de se fazer desde algumas versões do Windows atrás.

Comment: Opa, não é um vírus e eu não estou tentando simular o movimento do mouse. É um script que eu to fazendo pra aplicar prova nos laboratórios de informatica aqui na escola.

Comment: @JohnSchmitz por melhor que seja a intenção, o programa que você se propõe a fazer tem características de um malware. Se você conseguir burlar a segurança do Windows para fazê-lo funcionar (é possível, por exemplo, ao se emular um dispositivo USB), possivelmente todos os anti-vírus do mercado dirão que o seu programa é um malware dos mais perigosos.

Comment: Então foi o meu approach ao problema, que tipo solução pode ser implementada nesse caso? Por causa de como a arquitetura da rede daqui funciona, desligar a placa de rede não iria ajudar, já que é preciso estar conectado a rede local, então a minha solução foi desabilitar o proxy dos computadores...

Comment: @JohnSchmitz eu entendo o seu problema. Infra não é a minha área, então infelizmente eu não consigo pensar em nada além de configurar cada máquina manualmente. Talvez você consiga poupar tempo se configurar uma única máquina virtual, e carregar a mesma imagem dessa máquina em todas as máquinas físicas que for utilizar... Daí seus alunos podem fazer a prova nas VM's.

Comment: @JohnSchmitz eu já fui, ao mesmo tempo, aluno e funcionário de uma faculdade. Meu curso era de Ciência da Computação e eu era monitor de laboratório e membro da equipe de TI. Eu entendo o equilíbrio delicado que é proteger a rede da escola/faculdade ao mesmo tempo em que se libera acesso ao que é essencial para professores e alunos. Infelizmente isso é algo que não é simples :( eu espero que você encontre uma boa solução para o seu problema.

Comment: -1 - "isso não é possível" é simplesmente falso, visto que é possível.

Comment: Pelo contrário,  o que "não seria possível" seria desabilitar qualquer forma de fazer isso - mesmo se a microsoft quebrasse as APIs oficiais, ainda seria possível contornar isso por vários caminhos. Não confunda "eu acredito que você não deveria criar uma solução que dependa disso" com "não é possível".

Comment: @Renan Tchê, boa noite, perdoe fazer o comentário! Entendas   que minha participação na plataforma apenas opera em responder perguntas,não estou motivado em provar o que é possível nem o que não é possível, nem contrapor qualquer resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar criar um arquivo proxy.reg:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyServer"="http://<proxyEndereco>:<porta>"
```

Se quiser executar em um bat basta:

```
regedit /s "c:\caminho\proxy.reg"
```

Ou fazer um bat para alterar direto no registro:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d <proxyEndereco>:<porta> /f
```

Você esta alterando somente o ProxyEnable

Resetar configurações da rede:

```
NETSH INT IP RESET all
netsh winsock reset all
ipconfig /release 
Ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Então, eu só quero mudar o estado desse registro mesmo, por questão de comodidade, já que os Browsers usam as configurações do sistema de elas estão desabilitadas no browser também vai estar. O problema tá naquela GUI, as alterações só acontecem quando eu aperto aquele botão de "OK" eu queria simular aquele ok por linha de comando.

Comment: Você já tentou fechar e abri de novo o browser? Pode ser que ele inicia com o proxy x e não atualiza, então quando você vai nas configurações ele só atualiza.

Comment: Já testei com eles tanto aberto como fechado, essas mudanças (mudar de tanto pra  0 ou 1 o valor do registro) só funcionam apertando aquele ok mesmo...

Comment: Editei minha resposta, tente os últimos comandos.